# Why importing the images from an input directory using filedialog.askdirectory() leads to different result compared with using a direct and fix path?

Tags: image, path, filedialog

I can't understand why results of running the 1st and 2nd versions of the below code are different?!. I expect that the both versions resize the image; however, the image is resized only if it has been opened using filedialog.askdirectory (i.e. version 2):

First version:

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Manual:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Manual")
        window_width = 800
        window_height = 600
        screen_width = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.root.winfo_screenheight()
        x = int((screen_width / 2) - (window_width / 2))
        y = int((screen_height / 2) - (window_height / 2))
        self.root.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{x}+{y}")
        self.canvas = None
        self.folder_path = ""
        self.image_files = []
        self.current_image = 0
        self.total_images = 0
        self.image = None


        # Option 1:

        self.in_path = r"C:\Users\Markazi.co\Desktop\input 3"


        self.canvas_frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.canvas_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.canvas_scrollbar_x = ttk.Scrollbar(self.canvas_frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
        self.canvas_scrollbar_x.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)

        self.canvas_scrollbar_y = ttk.Scrollbar(self.canvas_frame)
        self.canvas_scrollbar_y.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.canvas_frame, bg='white', xscrollcommand=self.canvas_scrollbar_x.set,
                                yscrollcommand=self.canvas_scrollbar_y.set)
        self.canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.canvas_scrollbar_x.config(command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.canvas_scrollbar_y.config(command=self.canvas.yview)


    def open_folder(self):

        # Option 2:

        #self.in_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
        if self.in_path:
            self.image_files = sorted([f for f in os.listdir(self.in_path) if f.lower().endswith('.jpg')])
            self.total_images = len(self.image_files)
            self.open_image()

    def open_image(self):
        if self.current_image < self.total_images:
            image_file = self.image_files[self.current_image]
            self.image = Image.open(os.path.join(self.in_path, image_file))
            self.show_image(image_file, self.current_image + 1, self.total_images)
        else:
            self.canvas.delete("all")
            self.canvas.pack_forget()  # Hide the canvas


    def show_image(self, image_file, current_image, total_images):
        if self.image:
            width, height = self.calculate_image_size()

            self.image = self.image.resize((width, height), Image.LANCZOS)

            self.tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)

            self.canvas.config(scrollregion=(0, 0, width, height))
            self.canvas.delete("all")


            self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tk.NW, image=self.tk_image)


    def calculate_image_size(self):
        if self.image:
            window_width = self.root.winfo_width()
            window_height = self.root.winfo_height()
            border = 20
            max_width = window_width - (2 * border)
            max_height = window_height - (2 * border)

            image_ratio = self.image.width / self.image.height
            window_ratio = max_width / max_height

            if image_ratio > window_ratio:
                width = max_width
                height = int(max_width / image_ratio)
            else:
                width = int(max_height * image_ratio)
                height = max_height

            return width, height


root = tk.Tk()
root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
app = Manual(root)
app.open_folder()  # Call open_folder() to open the folder only once
root.mainloop()
```

The second version (using filedialog.askdirectory()):

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Manual:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Manual")
        window_width = 800
        window_height = 600
        screen_width = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.root.winfo_screenheight()
        x = int((screen_width / 2) - (window_width / 2))
        y = int((screen_height / 2) - (window_height / 2))
        self.root.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{x}+{y}")
        self.canvas = None
        self.folder_path = ""
        self.image_files = []
        self.current_image = 0
        self.total_images = 0
        self.image = None


        # Option 1:

        #self.in_path = r"C:\Users\Markazi.co\Desktop\input 3"


        self.canvas_frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.canvas_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.canvas_scrollbar_x = ttk.Scrollbar(self.canvas_frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
        self.canvas_scrollbar_x.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)

        self.canvas_scrollbar_y = ttk.Scrollbar(self.canvas_frame)
        self.canvas_scrollbar_y.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.canvas_frame, bg='white', xscrollcommand=self.canvas_scrollbar_x.set,
                                yscrollcommand=self.canvas_scrollbar_y.set)
        self.canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.canvas_scrollbar_x.config(command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.canvas_scrollbar_y.config(command=self.canvas.yview)


    def open_folder(self):

        # Option 2:

        self.in_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
        if self.in_path:
            self.image_files = sorted([f for f in os.listdir(self.in_path) if f.lower().endswith('.jpg')])
            self.total_images = len(self.image_files)
            self.open_image()

    def open_image(self):
        if self.current_image < self.total_images:
            image_file = self.image_files[self.current_image]
            self.image = Image.open(os.path.join(self.in_path, image_file))
            self.show_image(image_file, self.current_image + 1, self.total_images)
        else:
            self.canvas.delete("all")
            self.canvas.pack_forget()  # Hide the canvas


    def show_image(self, image_file, current_image, total_images):
        if self.image:
            width, height = self.calculate_image_size()

            self.image = self.image.resize((width, height), Image.LANCZOS)

            self.tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)

            self.canvas.config(scrollregion=(0, 0, width, height))
            self.canvas.delete("all")


            self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tk.NW, image=self.tk_image)


    def calculate_image_size(self):
        if self.image:
            window_width = self.root.winfo_width()
            window_height = self.root.winfo_height()
            border = 20
            max_width = window_width - (2 * border)
            max_height = window_height - (2 * border)

            image_ratio = self.image.width / self.image.height
            window_ratio = max_width / max_height

            if image_ratio > window_ratio:
                width = max_width
                height = int(max_width / image_ratio)
            else:
                width = int(max_height * image_ratio)
                height = max_height

            return width, height


root = tk.Tk()
root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
app = Manual(root)
app.open_folder()  # Call open_folder() to open the folder only once
root.mainloop()
```

This is a brief version of a more detailed code. Is this a python bug?

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that all of the variables you are using have the values you expect?

Comment: Yes. For instance, I have checked various images with different size and addresses.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by ChatGPT 3.5, adding "root.update()" at the end of the code, solved the problem:

```
...
root = tk.Tk()
root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
app = Manual(root)
root.update()  # Update the window to ensure the size is final
app.open_folder()  # Call open_folder() to open the folder only once
root.mainloop()
```